# Center of Pie Segment - Android

Tags: android, math, pie-chart

I'm using the HoloGraphLibrary for Android, but I need the percentage of each segment inside the pie chart (in its segment).

Because there isn't any coordinate system, I can't just find the segment and add some text, so I need a clever trick to do it. The only values I have at my disposal are:
 - The midX and midY coordinate of the pie chart
 - The inner and outer radius
 - each segments sweep (or angle our of 360 it covers)

I've managed to get the Y coordinate of the label, but using the same method for the X coordinate isn't yielding the correct result. This is the code I have so far:

```
canvas.drawText(slice.getTitle(), (float) (midX + (innerRadius + (radius - innerRadius)/2)*-1*Math.cos((currentSweep-padding)/2*(Math.PI/180) )), (float) (midY - (innerRadius + (radius - innerRadius)/2)*Math.cos((currentSweep)/2*(Math.PI/180))), paint);
```

Can anyone help with centring the label in the segment?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok my bad,
This is an answer :

```
// add a text title centered in each slice :
        textAngle += currentSweep;
        mBlackColorPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        System.out.println("title : " + slice.getTitle() +  "Sweep : "+currentSweep + " Angle = "+currentAngle);
        canvas.drawText(slice.getTitle(),
                (float) (midX + (innerRadius + (radius - innerRadius)/2)*Math.sin((textAngle)*(Math.PI/360) )),
                (float) (midY - (innerRadius + (radius - innerRadius)/2)*Math.cos((textAngle)*(Math.PI/360))),
                mBlackColorPaint);
        textAngle += currentSweep;
```

put this in the onDraw() method after setting the Region object

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's working for me.

```
canvas.drawText(slice.getTitle(),
                        (float) (midX + (innerRadius + (radius - innerRadius)/2)*Math.sin((currentSweep)*(Math.PI/360) )),
                        (float) (midY - (innerRadius + (radius - innerRadius)/2)*Math.cos((currentSweep)*(Math.PI/360))),
                        mPaint);
```